# Restore overwritten/sync'ed IntelliJ settings

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just bought PhpStorm, and selected Settings Sync, and I selected to sync across JB products, hoping everything from my years of WebStorm would sync to PhpStorm.

And of course now I see different colors in WebStorm because it looks like maybe it took on the PhpStorm colors. I can confirm that I'm still on my "Visual Studio Code Dark Plus" as I was before.

It does look like my keyboard shortcuts are still what they were, thankfully!

How can I make sure I'm syncing correctly?

Comment: Hello! When enabling the Settings Sync, did you see the option to push current settings to the cloud or pull them from the cloud? Also, could you please specify what exactly you mean by "different colors" there? Is the whole IDE theme changed, or only the color scheme in the Editor?